# how to integrate react application with filemaker server as backend

Tags: reactjs, filemaker

My job has tasked me to create a login page with username, password, reset password, sign in and sign up. When you login you are sent to a landing page. All should be done with react but i have to use filemaker server as a backend that stores usernames and passwords in a database. I've never used filemaker before and i don't know where to start. Any advise will be appreciated

Comment: We use Go as the middle tier and use ODBC to talk to filemaker - Our authentication process sends back a JSON Web Token (JWT) which our React app sends in as an authorization header. No need to bounce to FileMaker layouts unless you want to.

Comment: @KeithJohnHutchison Does that mean my react app can be on a separate server and communicate with my filemaker database?

Comment: Your React app can be on a separate server.

Comment: Its all very complicated but thanks for the help

Comment: A FileMaker database in your server can easily handle the login system using FileMaker Data API. Not very complicated if you can handle the API.

Comment: "Does that mean my react app can be on a separate server and communicate with my filemaker database?" -  Yes - We use our own middle tier go server running on the same device as the FileMaker server. If you decided to use the FileMaker Data API you would not need to roll your middle tier. We started with the Data API and decided to drop it when we discovered it only works with FileMaker tables. Another way forward would be to use FileMaker to connect to Postgres, Mysql or Mssql and connect using industry standard tools to the database - that's the route we're taking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Filemaker Data Api:
https://help.claris.com/en/data-api-guide/

1. Login call to get the token
2. Make a POST request to
   {yourServerUrl}/fmi/data/version/databases/{database-name}/layouts/{layout-name}/records

to write the new record into the database.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your company is on a recent version of FileMaker (version 16 or later, I believe) then FileMaker Server has a feature called the Data API that publishes all FM data in a more standard-manner than going through the trials of ODBC or the PHP API.

The requirements are essentially just clicking the checkbox in the Server Admin control panel:
[image]

That feature has tiered pricing associated with it, but it includes a base amount of requests as part of having a server license and most likely you will find it to be the best avenue.  If, for some reason, you can't use the Data API, going in via the PHP API which produces a more verbose XML output and is tied to fields visible on layouts is another avenue.